# Arbitrage between markets

Tags: trading, arbitrage, currency

I'm trying to understand how arbitrage works, but I'm having some difficulties based on some restrictions:

- I have markets A, B and C.
- The currencies that are traded are X <-> Y, and X <-> Z.
- The only thing that can be transferred between markets A, B and C is currency X.
- The time it takes to transfer the funds (in currency X) between any market is about 2-10 minutes.
- The opportunity for arbitrage last for about 1 hour.

The exchange rates on market A

- 1 X exchanges for 3.22 Y
- 1 X exchanges for 5.11 Z

The exchange rates on market B

- 1 X exchanges for 3.25 Y
- 1 X exchanges for 5.07 Z

The exchange rate on market C

- Does not exchange X <-> Y
- 1 X exchanges for 4.98 Z

Suppose that exchange A is the exchange with the highest volume and presumably the most accurate exchange rate. How can one take advantage of the arbitrage opportunities if the only thing that can be transferred between exchanges is currency X and it takes 2-10 minutes?

Comment: Have you looked at Triangular Arbitrage? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_arbitrage

Comment: @QuantGuy yes, but that presumes that if that you can "easily" take your currency between adjacent markets in currency other than X. In the situation I'm exploring, it's only feasible to move currency X between the markets, which seems to defeat the purpose of arbitrage (or at least that's how I see it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a stylized example of the classic [dual-listed companies "arbitrage"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrage#Dual-listed_companies), the most famous example of which is Royal Dutch Shell.  It is not a pure arbitrage, but rather is a case of "statistical arbitrage", specifically [pairs trading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairs_trade).

First, express the prices of Y and Z in terms of X, and let's rename X "\$" for convenience's sake.  Then Y costs about \$0.311 in market A and \$0.308 in market B.  Assuming no bid/ask spread, therefore you should buy Y in B and sell it in A.  Z costs \$0.196, \$0.197, \$0.201 in A, B, and C, respectively, so buy Z in A and sell it in C.  Since money (X) is transferable between markets, you can use one market as a funding source for another, so that all arbitrages can be set up to have zero cost at inception.

Comment: That's a very helpful answer! However, if you buy Y for $0.311, you're holding Y and you can't transfer it to A to sell it. Same thing with buying Z in A, you're holding Z and you can't transfer it to C to sell it. The only thing that can transfer between the exchanges is X. I think I like the idea of pairs trading better, it might be a better option to trade when the correlation weakens...

Comment: The idea behind pairs trading is that you never actually exchange Y in one market for Y in another market, you just wait for the prices to cross.

Comment: Oh, so you're describing pairs trading, I thought your example involved transferring currency. Is it possible to do pairs trading on a market that doesn't allow shorting?

Comment: @Lirik No, you need to be able to sell short in order to do practically any sort of arbitrage.

Comment: I guess the other option is to simply get a lot of funds and buy X in market A, transfer X to market B, sell X, then take the long trip around (could be a couple of days) to re-fund A. If the flow is consistent and the money is big enough, then it might be feasible. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @Lirik that presumes you have something in market A with which to buy X.  Otherwise, you're still selling something short, Y or Z, in market A in order to buy X.

Comment: The terminology is confusing me a bit: "selling something short". As far as I understand it, taking a short position occurs when you're selling something which you don't have. Simply selling something implies that you have it. So I find the term "selling short" to be confusing: you're either selling or shorting, but I don't know how you can do both. It's much more difficult (time consuming and expensive) to transfer non-X currency between the markets I'm dealing with, but it's possible...

Comment: Ah, turns out you can do arbitrage with currency even if shorting is not allowed... for example: if I'm supposed to short USD/EUR, I can just buy the EUR/USD and that should be the same.

Comment: @Lirik you seem very confused about the definition of short selling.  Please consult [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_%28finance%29).  Some people have also found the [money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com) helpful for such beginner questions regarding definitions.

Comment: I'm familiar with how shorting works in general, but I'm not very familiar with arbitrage. You helped a lot with the arbitrage explanation, but then I was trying to figure out how to "simulate" shorting on an exchange that does not allow it in order to do arbitrage. Buying the inverse currency pair seems to behave like shorting a currency pair.

Comment: I guess my terminology was off... short selling is the same as shorting. I just thought that calling it "short selling" is redundant, but I guess it's the official term.